# Limit IIS virtual Directories pointing to same folder path

Tags: iis

I have an asp.net project that I use for a couple different purposes.  We have addresses that access the same virtual directory via different paths (**use1.company.com** and **use2.company.com**)  I do not want to break the project up as they use similar functionality that seems redundant to have in two places.  None the less as it stands **use1.company.com/default.aspx** and **use2.company.com/default.aspx** both are the same.  I want to make it so that **use2.company.aspx/default.aspx** is not accessible.  Is there a way to do that from the **App Pool/Virtual Directory settings** or do I just have to hope that external users dont type **/default.aspx**?

I know I can set the default document to like **survey.aspx** (purpose of the second url) but that does not prevent some savvy users from typing in **default.aspx** just to see what it does.  Any assistance here would be great.

Comment: How about redirecting use2.company.com/default.aspx to use1.company.com? You can do a redirect for a specific file in IIS or in the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Since they point to the same .aspx file could you not include an if statement at the start of the file to grab the URL and if it includes use2 then go back?